# Having difficulty displaying and centering map with user's location using W3C GeoLocation API

Tags: jquery, geolocation, google-maps-api-3, geoapi

I'm using the following script and having difficulty passing in the lat and lon variables I created with user's location. When I remove the lat and lon variables I created and manually put in 0,0 it works fine for debugging's sake...The map should be displayed in a div with id of map_canvas.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(handle_geolocation_query,handle_errors);  
var lat = position.coords.latitude;
var lon = position.coords.longitude;
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);
    var myOptions = {
    zoom: 1,
    center: latlng,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
    myOptions); map.setTilt(45); 
});
```

Comment: var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
    myOptions); can be changed to var map = new google.maps.Map($("#map_canvas"),
    myOptions);

Comment: 'position' comes from the W3C GeoLocation API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is probably right here:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(handle_geolocation_query, handle_errors);
```

Presumably, `handle_geolocation_query` looks something like this:

```
var position;
function handle_geolocation_query(pos) {
    position = pos;
}
```

But [`navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition`](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html#geolocation_interface) is an asynchronous function call:

> The `getCurrentPosition()` method takes one, two or three arguments. When called, it must immediately return and then **asynchronously attempt to obtain the current location of the device**. If the attempt is successful, the `successCallback` must be invoked [...]

Emphasis mine.

So, your `handle_geolocation_query` callback will be called by `getCurrentPosition` when it has the position, not when you call `getCurrentPosition`. So, when you get to here:

```
var lat = position.coords.latitude;
var lon = position.coords.longitude;
```

Your `position` won't necessarily contain anything useful and you probably get an error telling you that `position.coords` is undefined or not an object or something similar.

You need to move your `new google.maps.LatLng` and `new google.maps.Map` stuff to inside the `handle_geolocation_query` callback where you'll have a useful `position` value.

Answer (score 1):

http://j.maxmind.com/app/geoip.js

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true

```
 var ulat;
 var ulon;
 var map;

         if (navigator.geolocation)  {



       navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(handle_geolocation_query,handle_errors);

            }

            else if (!navigator.geolocation)

            {  
             max();  
            } 
             else
            { 
             alert("Sorry user location can't be detected");
              initialize();   
            }   



//maxmind api for fallback
        function max()  
        { 
              ulat=geoip_latitude();
              ulon=geoip_longitude();

            initialize();
        }  


        function handle_errors(error)  
        {  
            switch(error.code)  
            {  
                case error.PERMISSION_DENIED: alert("user did not share geolocation data");  
                break;  

                case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE: alert("could not detect current position");  
                break;  

                case error.TIMEOUT: alert("retrieving position timed out");  
                break;  

                default: alert("unknown error");  
                break;  
            } 
        initialize();    
        } 

        function handle_geolocation_query(position){ 

        ulat=position.coords.latitude;
        ulon=position.coords.longitude;
      /* alert('Lat: ' + position.coords.latitude +  
                  ' Lon: ' + position.coords.longitude); */ 

        initialize();
        } 


     function initialize(){
     loc = new Array();
     geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
      var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(ulat,ulon);
       var myOptions = {
       zoom: 3,
       center: latlng,
       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
     map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        myOptions);



}//end of initialize
```

Hi, geolocation is asynchronus by nature hence don't use it with synchronus function ,otherwise u may get null value for  new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon) function. try the above code according to your requirement.you can work similarly in jquery.